# The .bashrc file changed back after reload it

Tags: bashrc

I changed the `.bashrc` file and run `source ~/. bashrc` it changes back to the old one. Why?

Comment: Is that a typo? It must be `source ~/.bashrc` without a space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must logout to make changes work after editing .bashrc or .profile file

Comment: Not so, you just need to `source` it.